# Remove parameter within nginx rewrite

Tags: nginx, redirect, url-rewriting

I need to remove a specific parameter *on=ref* from url doing a redirect 301

```
https://www.example.com/1223/page.php?on=ref
https://www.example.com/1223/page.php?param=1&on=ref&param=2
```

They have to become

```
https://www.example.com/1223/page.php
https://www.example.com/1223/page.php?param=1&param=2
```

I'm try this

```
#remove on=ref
if ($args ~ ^(?:on)=[^&]*$ ) {
  rewrite ^ $uri? last;
}
if ($args ~ ^(?:on)=[^&]*(?:&(.*))?$ ) {
  rewrite ^ $uri?$1? last;
}
if ($args ~ ^(.*)&(?:on)=[^&]*(&.*)?$ ) {
  rewrite ^ $uri?$1$2? last;
}
if ($request_uri ~ \?(.*&)?(on)= ) {
  return 301 $uri$is_args$args;
}
```

but it always redirect to the homepage without any params

Someone can help me please?

Comment: if ($query_string ~ "^(.*)on=ref(.*)$") {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $uri? permanent;
}

Redirect to the uri without any params

Comment: Try: `if ($args ~ ^(.*)on=ref&?(.*)$) { return 301 $uri?$1$2; }`

Comment: i have a problem... if i have a url like "example.com?on=ref" it redirect to "example.com?".... how can I delete the "?"?

Comment: The `if` statements are evaluated in order. Just add another statement, to handle the special case. For example: `if ($args = "on=ref") { return 301 $uri; }` - but make sure you place it first!